# Doubt in Riesz Representation Theorem Proof (Bartle)

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I was reading Bartle's proof for the Riesz Representation Theorem, and I got stuck at one point. First, the proof is given for the case where $\mu$ is a finite measure. Then, to prove the case where $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, we consider $X= \cup F_n$, where $(F_n)$ is an increasing sequence of sets with finite measure. So, we have that for each $n$, there exists a nonnegative function $g_n$ such that

\begin{equation}
G(f\chi_{F_n}) = \int f \chi_{F_n}d\mu 
\end{equation}

for all $f \in L^1$. Now, what I don't understand is the following statement: if $m \leq n$, then $g_m(x)= g_n(x)$ for almost all $x \in F_m$.

Could someone help me, or even give me a hint of what I should do to prove that? I think it may be a simple argument, but I'm really stuck on it.

Edit: I think I may have solved it. If m $\leq$ n, we can separate:

\begin{equation}
G(f \chi_{F_n}) = \int f \chi_{F_n} g_n d\mu = \int f \chi_{F_m} g_n d\mu + \int f \chi_{F_m \setminus F_m}
\end{equation}

So,

\begin{equation}
G(f\chi_{F_n}) - G(f \chi_{F_m}) = \int f \chi_{F_m}(g_n-g_m)d\mu + \int f \chi_{F_n\setminus F_m}d\mu.
\end{equation}

On the other hand, by linearity of $G$, we have that

\begin{equation}
G(f \chi_{F_n} ) - G(f \chi_{F_m}) = G(f (\chi_{F_n} - \chi_{F_m})) = G(f\chi_{F_n\setminus F_m}) = \int f \chi_{F_n\setminus F_m} d\mu.
\end{equation}

Thus, $\int f \chi_{F_m}(g_n-g_m)d\mu =0$, and we conclude that $g_n=g_m$ almost everywhere in $F_m$.

Please, take a look on what I've done and tell me if I made any mistakes. Thank you!

Comment: What is big $G$?

Comment: Also what's $g_n$? You introduce the notation but it's never involved in the condition afterwards.

Comment: G is a linear functional $G: L^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, such that if $G$ is nonnegative and $\mu$ is a finite measure, then $G(f) = \int f g d\mu$ for all $f \in L^1$.

Comment: $g_n$ is the function that represents the linear functional $G$ in $F_n$. Bartle proves that it exists such functions when we have a finite measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is that $F_n\subseteq F_{n+1}$ for each $n$ and that there is for such $n$, a $\textit{unique}\ g_n$ such that $G(f) = \int_{F_n} f g_nd\mu$ for all $f\in L^1(F_n),$ where we assume without loss of generality, that $f\ge 0.$

In what follows, identify $g_n$ with the function on $X$ that is zero on $X\setminus F_n.$

The uniqueness gives us a well-defined non-negative function $g=\bigcup_n g_n$ on $X=\bigcup_n F_n$ and the monotone convergence theorem shows that $\vert |g \vert|\le \vert | G\vert|$ so $g\in L^1(X).$

Now, let $f\in L^1(X).$ Then, an applcation of the dominated convergence theorem gives $\vert |G(f)-G(f\chi_n))\vert |=\vert |G(f-f\chi_n)\vert |\le \vert |G\vert|\vert| f-f\chi_n \vert|\to 0.$

To finish, apply this last result together with the monotone convergence theorem:

$G(f)=\lim  G(f\chi_n)=\lim \int_Xf\chi_ngd\mu=\int_X\lim f\chi_ngd\mu=\int_Xfgd\mu.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I got it now!

Comment: @ Yodair Glad to help!